# How Get Data From Json in Extjs

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

i have this store. my problem, i want get data from this Json.

```
Ext.define('DWP.store.Test', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

        fields: [
           {name: 'field1'},
           {name: 'field2'},
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'resources/data/load.php',
            reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'root'
            }
        },
         autoLoad: true,
   });
```

i tried this code to get the data from Json, but not worked. how can i get data from json?

```
 var json = Ext.encode(Ext.pluck(store.data.items, 'store'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have `autoLoad: true` this should looks like:

```
var store = Ext.getStore('DWP.store.Test');
    store.each(function (record, id) {
         console.log(record.get('field1'));
    });
```

if you prefer `autoLoad: false` this looks like:

```
var store = Ext.getStore('DWP.store.Test');
        store.load({
            callback: function (records, operation, success) {
                store.each(function (record, id) {
                    console.log(record.get('field1'));
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: if i use that functon, i cannot use them become a variable. do you have any solution, because i want use the Json Data to load again but to another store. please help me?

Comment: Why are you trying to duplicate store with the same values ? What is the purpose of that ?

Comment: yes, i have wrong way. so i ask you for the solution. actually i want load new data from different store but the name of field in two store is same, so i think can load data from another json to json. i want drilldown in my chart.js but the data from Mysql, but the data more than one. i confuse, i hope you can help me, because it is my first time using Extjs.

Comment: data from json to json ? You mean copy data from one store to another store that has the same model ?

Comment: yes the model is same. My case is i trying to build dashboard, the dashboard have charts which can drilldown data. Who make me confuse is the source data is mysql. So i must convert it to json if i want load data to my chart.js. do you have any solution to drilldown the chart but the source data in mysql. I hope your help. Thank you.

Comment: Every data that come in and come out in Extjs need to be in json format. There is no other normal possibilty to do that. So you have to parse data from mysql to json.